# Obtener el listado de pacientes que se han antendido con un medico, contanto el total de citas antes realizada en MySql

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener el listado de pacientes de un medico, y en ese listado totalizar las veces que ese paciente se ha atendido con ese medico (estado = 4), pero hay pacientes que aun no se han atendido con el medico porque tienen la hora en estado pendiente o tienen la hora anulada. Los pacientes con horas anuladas o pendientes también deben aparecer en el listado, y en la columna total debiese aparecer como 0 o null

Con las respuesta y comentarios recibidos, he logrado la siguiente consulta

```
select count(hr.paciente_id) as total,
       p.nombre_completo
from pacientes p
left outer join horas hr on p.id = hr.paciente_id 
where hr.medico_id = 1 and (hr.estado = 4 or hr.paciente_id is not null)
group by p.id
order by p.nombre_completo
```

El total de pacientes que me entrega la consulta es el correcto, pero me esta dejando en 1 los pacientes que tienen horas anuladas o pendientes.

Por ejemplo la fila dos, debiese ser 0 o null o empty (cualquiera de estos valores me sirve)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**@UPDATE**

Gracias a @SJuan76, logre dar con el objetivo

```
select count(if(hr.estado = 4, 1, null)) as total, 
       p.nombre_completo
from pacientes p
   left join horas hr on p.id = hr.paciente_id 
where hr.medico_id = 1 
group by p.id
order by p.nombre_completo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Perdón si he realizado algo mal en la formulación de la pregunta, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: intentaste condicionar tu consulta con is not null?

Comment: Deberías explicar mejor el modelo de datos. Por ejemplo, mirando las tablas y campos de la consulta, no veo "este paciente es de este médico", sino "este paciente fue atendido una vez por este médico", lo cual no es lo mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a intentar dar una respuesta más canónica para principiantes y que sirva de referencia:

## Cómo funciona una consulta SQL

Lo siguiente es una descripción *a alto nivel* de como funcionan las consultas en bases de datos relacionales.

Esto significa que las consultas dan un resultado como si siguieran este proceso, aunque en la práctica los motores de BD pueden hacer las cosas de forma diferente a nivel interno.

### Producto cartesiano

De las tablas involucradas en la consulta, se hace el producto cartesiano (todas las combinaciones posibles)

```
Tabla A: 
   Registro 1: r1, d1, d2
   Registro 2: r2, d3, d4
   Registro 3: r3, d5, d6
Tabla B:
   Registro 1: s1, e1, r1
   Registro 2: s2, e2, r3

select * from tablaA, tablaB;

r1, d1, d2, s1, e1, r1
r2, d3, d4, s1, e1, r1
r3, d5, d6, s1, e1, r1
r1, d1, d2, s2, e2, r3
r2, d3, d4, s2, e2, r3
r3, d5, d6, s2, e2, r3
```

### Selección de registros

Con las cláusulas `WHERE`, o las cláusulas `ON` en los `JOIN`, filtras los registros que cumplan una determinada condición:

```
select * from tablaA, tablaB WHERE tablaA.campo1 = 'r1';

r1, d1, d2, s1, e1, r1
r1, d1, d2, s2, e2, r3

select * from tablaA join tablaB On tablaA.campo1 = tablaB.campo3;

r1, d1, d2, s1, e1, r1
r3, d5, d6, s2, e2, r3
```

#### Outer joins

Un tipo especial de joins son los `outer join`, en que si los registros de una de las tablas no van a aparecer porque ningún registro de la otra tabla no cumplen la condición `ON`, los registros aparecen sin estar "combinados" con ningún valor

```
select * from tablaA left outer join tablaB On tablaA.campo1 = tablaB.campo3; // left, los registros de A siempre aparecerán

r1, d1, d2, s1, e1, r1
r2, d3, d4, null, null, null
r3, d5, d6, s2, e2, r3
```

### Selección de campos

```
select tablaA.campo1, tablaA.campo2, tablaB.campo1 from tablaA, tablaB;

r1, d1, r1
r2, d3, r1
r3, d5, r1
r1, d1, r3
r2, d3, r3
r3, d5, r3
```

### Funciones de agregación

```
select count(*) from tablaA, tablaB;

6

select tablaA.campo1, count(*) from tablaA, tablaB;

r1, 2  // En el producto cartesiano hay dos filas con tablaA.campo1 = 'r1'
r2, 2
r3, 2
```

#### Ejemplo de la pregunta.

Necesitas un left outer join para que los pacientes sin "horas" aparezcan.
Los pacientes sin horas apareceran con los campos de "horas" en null; así que si pones un filtro (en el WHERE o en el JOIN) que elimine registros, puedes perder las filas que no cumplan la condición y ya no aparecerán en la select.

La solución es no filtrar filas (por médico o estado) y hacer las comprobaciones en las funciones de agregación:

```
select count(if(hr.medico_id=1 and hr.estado=4, 1, null)),
   p.nombre_completo
from paciente p
   left outer join horas hr on p.id = hr.paciente_id 
where hr.medico_id = 1 
   and hr.estado = 4
group by p.id
order by p.nombre_completo;
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no es lo que busco. Quiero obtener el listado de pacientes de un medico, y en ese listado totalizar las veces que ese paciente se ha atendido con ese medico, pero hay pacientes que aun no se han atendido con el medico porque tienen la hora en estado pendiente o tienen la hora anulada. Los pacientes con horas anuladas o pendientes también deben aparecer en el listado, y en la columna total debiese aparecer como 0 o null pienso yo

Comment: intente con left outer join, pero me deja afuera a los pacientes con horas pendiente o anuladas.

Comment: simplemente maravilloso SJuan76. una pregunta left join y left outer join me retorna la misma información hay alguna diferencia entre este tipo de uniones?

Comment: y lo otro es que tuve que mantener en el where "hr.paciente_id is not null" si no lo hacia no me retornaba los pacientes con horas nulas o pendientes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server. Es lo mismo. Y lo de `hr.paciente_id is not null` no tiene mucho sentido si el modelo está correcto porque A) significa que tienes consultas sin pacientes :-S y B) en el join ya se filtra de todas formas.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta solución de incluir una select dentro de otra select:

```
select count(hr.paciente_id) as total,
(select max(hr.fecha_hora) from horas hr where p.id = hr.paciente_id AND hr.medico_id = 1 AND hr.estado = 4) as fecha_hora,
p.nombre_completo
from pacientes p
left join horas hr on p.id = hr.paciente_id 
where hr.medico_id = 1  
group by p.id
order by p.nombre_completo;
```